# Swift 3 : Tab Bar Controller Image Size Issue

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, assets

I'm trying to add image in my tab bar. I created all images for universal devices, but when I add the images, it look too big for tab controller. How can I fix this problem.

This is my assets folder : 
[image]

And this happens when i add the icon :
[image]

Comment: make the assets correct size, there is no point in making all size assets the same size

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because the image is to big :)

Here is the Apple recommendations: https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/graphics/custom-icons/

Comment: yeah, I realized that my designer gave me a different size of images that I needed. Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 3):

The size of the image used is too big..

Please follow size guideline provided by apple to get the best result

Have a look[image]